# PHP time() sometimes off by a few seconds, then correct next time it is called

Tags: php, epoch

I have a simple php program running on a black-boxed web service, that uses the `time()` function. I've noticed that the `time()` function is not particularly consistent in my program. I am displaying the time on a webpage and when I refresh the page, the updated time is displayed.

Sometimes when I refresh, the time jumps ahead by between `50` and `100` seconds, then next time I refresh the page it jumps back to a lower (more consistent) Unix timestamp, consistent to the time shown 2 refreshes previous.

The code is simply:

```
<?php 
    echo(time()); 
?>
```

#### Question

Why would the result of the `time()` function sometimes be off by a few seconds, then correct the next time?

Comment: I never faced such issue with `time()`. It can't get lower for sure.

Comment: Strange. Possibly something to do with my server configuration? I am also completely baffled.

Comment: `time()` is based on your server's time so it sounds like your server's clock is having some sort of issue. Sounds like it's synchronizing to a bad datasource and then reverting or something.

Comment: It could be that your machines clock has drifted, then it synchronises with the time servers and corrected itself.

Comment: That is possible - I am using a web service that is black-boxed to me in that regard

Comment: what is your server time?

Comment: If you are running it on a web service that load balances on multiple web servers it's likely one of the web heads time is out of sync with the rest.

Comment: @R. Chappell, on further investigation -  I am quite sure that your idea is correct. If you choose to submit an answer, I will accept it. I have edited the original question to include the key detail about the black-boxed web service. I'm sure this question could help someone in a similar situation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `time()` function can sometimes give different results when running across multiple servers. A load balancer can direct you to a server where the time will be consistent. If the load balancer then directs you to a different server where the system clock has drifted you could get a different result from the `time()` function.

Other cases where the time can be incorrect one moment and correct another is if the systems clock had drifted. Then during the course of a re-sync with the time servers it had updated the time causing you to lose or gain time.